# How can I make rxjs-spy's let operator work?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

How can I change the value of an observable **multiple** times using [rxjs-spy](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-spy)'s [let()](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-spy#module-let) method?

I was following [this introduction](https://cartant.github.io/rxjs-spy/) of the tool and when I came up to the example for using let():
`spy.let("people", source => source.mapTo("mallory"));`
I got stuck because `source` is an `Observable<any>` which does not have a `mapTo()` method. So this line should *just work* when pasted into my chrome console but since mapTo() is long gone it throws an exception.

The only method that I could think of didn't work. This allows me to access the rxjs operators

```
// In a top level typescript file (I add this file to debug builds only)
// This just lets me use rxjs operators, of, and tag, in the chrome console
import { tag } from 'rxjs-spy/operators/tag';
import { create } from 'rxjs-spy';
import * as operators from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
window['debug'] = {
  rxjs: { operators, of },
  spy: { tag }
};
const spy = create();
```

then I have an observable somewhere

```
myObservable.pipe(
  tag("foo")
)
```

And in the chrome console. (note: I have also tried this without using pipe and tag)

```
spy.let("foo", fooObservable => window.debug.rxjs
    .of(1)
    .pipe(
        window.debug.spy.tag("foo")
    )
);
```

**This only works the first time I try to update the value**. And I feel like this is way too much work anyway.

The last issue I'm not understanding is after using `spy.let(...)` I thought that `spy.undo(1)` (replacing 1 with whatever value is correct at the time) might be able to help me test multiple values but it blows out the snapshots, giving me something like:

```
spy.show()
0 snapshot(s) matching /.+/
```

I also get this warning a lot while using the tool

```
index.js:3551 Cyclic next detected; type = subject; value = [object Object]; subscribed at
Observable._subscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:291983:33)
Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:291934:22)
http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:291217:44
notify_ (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:291076:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -- I was just missing the `complete` option. The issue seems to be caused because `let()` defaults `complete` to `true`.

So again I still have a file that I use in my debug build. This allows me to use rxjs operators, of, and  in the chrome console:

```
// import { tag } from 'rxjs-spy/operators/tag'; You shouldn't need this in the console.
import { create } from 'rxjs-spy';
import * as operators from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
window['debug'] = { rxjs: { operators, of } };
const spy = create();
```

Then in the console I set the complete option to `false`. Depending on what you're doing this may not apply, but I wanted to continue updating a value by hand to view the result of a change.

```
// Add { complete: false } to the parameter list.
spy.let("foo", fooObservable => window.debug.rxjs.of(8), { complete: false });
```